# unobtrusive Ajax is preventing onsuccess from firing in MVC5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-ajax

I have an Ajax call that works just fine when I do not have the unobtrusive Ajax script referenced. When I add it to the page it prevents the onSuccess Javascript from firing. When trying to render a partial view with the script referenced everything works just fine. Also, what is weird is that the onSuccess function triggers when the page first loads.

To clarify, I have the script referenced at the bottom of my DOM and the web.config file has it enabled. When using the browser debug, I see that the AJAX is successful, it just does not make it to the javascript onSuccess method. Here is my code:

**Reference to the scripts:**

```
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.10.4.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/AAData.js")

    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

**AJAX Call:**

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Search", "Home", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "onSuccess", HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "Search" }))
{

    <div class="col-md-6 form-inline">

        <div class="form-group" style="width:85%;">
            <div class="right-inner-addon">
                <i class=" glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                <input type="text" data-autocomplete="@Url.Action("Quicksearch","Home")" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="q" value="@ViewBag.CurrenetFilter" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default form-inline" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
        <br />

    </div>
}
```

**Controller:**

```
   public ActionResult Search(string q, int? page,  string catb = null)
    {
        return Json(new { url = Url.Action("Search", "Items", new { query = q, pageNum = page, categoryB = catb }) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

**Javascript:**

```
var onSuccess = function (result) {
    if (result.url) {
        // if the server returned a JSON object containing an url 
        // property we redirect the browser to that url
        window.location.href = result.url;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shifted the ordering of the scripts and updated jquery to the latest in order to fix this. Scripts are in the following order:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Jquery is version 2.1.1

unobtrusive ajax is 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using OnComplete instead of OnSuccess?

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete(v=vs.118).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxoptions.oncomplete%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)